# Using ADODataset component to open an Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: delphi, excel, ado

I'm using **ADOdataset** component to view an Excel Spreadsheet on a Delphi form.

The component requires that the **CommandText** property be set to the name of a spreadsheet in the workbook being opened.

How can I set this property to open the first spreadsheet in the workbook regardless of the name?

---

```
procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject); 
   var   XLSFile, CStr : string; 
begin    
   if OpenDialog1.Execute() then 
   begin
       XLSFile := OpenDialog1.FileName;

       CStr := 'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='   
           +XLSFile+'; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;Persist Security Info=False';

       ADODataSet1.Active := False;    
       ADODataSet1.ConnectionString := Cstr;    
       ADODataSet1.CommandText := ??????????; 
       ADODataSet1.Active := True;
    end;    
 end;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't, you have to know the name of the page. Use a [`TADOConnection`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/ADODB_TADOConnection.html) to connect to the work book so that you can call [`GetTableNames`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/ADODB_TADOConnection_GetTableNames@TStrings@Boolean.html) to retrieve the names of pages. There's an example [here](http://delphi.about.com/od/database/l/aa090903b.htm). Then you can set the `Connection` property of an ADO data set or an ADO query to the connection object and run a query.

Comment: How do you deal with the TADODataSet always using the first row as field names? I actually have values and multi-cell spanning on the first line.

Comment: Nevermind. I found that you need to include HDR=NO in the extended properties of the connection string. https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/help/278973/excelado-demonstrates-how-to-use-ado-to-read-and-write-data-in-excel-w

Answer (score 1):

While I am sure someone will provide an answer to your question, I would like to suggest, if it is at all appropriate, that you consider an alternative approach.  Take a look at [NativeExcel](http://www.nika-soft.com/nativeexcel2/).  For your immediate need, you can access the spreadsheets by sheet name or index.  The first sheet is found as Book.Sheets[[1](http://www.nika-soft.com/nativeexcel2/)].  The developer maintains a very nice support document delivered as a help file or online [here](http://www.nika-soft.com/nativeexcel2/doc/index.htm).  I have used the library for a couple of years and found it to be very stable and powerful.

Answer (score -2):

Add property:

```
ADODataSet1.CommandType := cmdUnknown;
```